# Re Positioning iframes by hide/show

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, css-position

I have the current code, which hides/shows iframes (external pages rendering text columns via cgi - displayed left to right) via buttons at the top of the page. Right now the iframes are positioned using absolute, but I would like them to 'reorder' and change location depending on which are hidden vs shown.
EX: if only 2 iframes are shown, they would reduce the left right space occupied.
This is important, as I will be adding more content than can fit on the page at a time. (Also, I am trying to change the Jscript to hide everything by default, instead of show on page load)

```js
    function myFunctionui() {

      var x = document.getElementById('ui');

      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctiontic() {
      var x = document.getElementById('tic');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctionlab() {
      var x = document.getElementById('lab');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctionzone1_4() {
      var x = document.getElementById('zone1_4');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctionzone5() {
      var x = document.getElementById('zone5');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctionslas() {
      var x = document.getElementById('slas');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctionhiks() {
      var x = document.getElementById('hiks');
      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tic {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
#lab {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
#zone1_4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 420;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
#zone5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 630;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
#slas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 840;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
#hiks {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1050;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 60px;
}
iframe {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  seamless;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionui()">^</button>

<div id="ui">
  <button onclick="myFunctiontic()">TICs</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionlab()">LABs</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionzone1_4()">ZONE 1-4</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionzone5()">ZONE 5</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionslas()">SLAS</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionhiks()">HIKS</button>
</div>


<div id="tic">
  <iframe src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/ticstatus/ticstatus.cgi" width="130" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="lab">
  <iframe src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/labstatus/labstatus.cgi" width="130" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="zone1_4">
  <iframe src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/lastations1_4.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="zone5">
  <iframe src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/lastations5.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="slas">
  <iframe src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/slastations.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="hiks">

  <iframe src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/hiksstations.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Do they have to be position:absolute?

Comment: nope, I just did that temporarily, I don't know how else to keep them from stacking on top of each other

Comment: Why is the body and html overflow:hidden?

Comment: i'm not sure, might that be part of the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for late response. I was just wondering because I was working with a small screen and it would be nice if it wasn't there. Do you need the overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

First of all, get rid of the `position:absolute` idea because there is a much easier way to fix this.

Also, do not wrap the iframes in `div`s. Divs are block elements, meaning they will deliberately break a line, but iframes are inline, meaning they break lines only when the line reaches the end of the screen as you can see in the words of this answer. (If you want, however, you can wrap ALL of the iframes in a `div`.)

I recommend that you get rid of `overflow: hidden` for the html and body just so that smaller screens can see what you want.

The only CSS you need is for the iframe: `white-space: nowrap` so that the lines never break and `#iframeContainer {display: none}` because you wanted everything like that by default with the same thing for its child iframes.

There is a problem in you JavaScript that can easily be fixed. As I mentioned earlier, iframes are inline. However, in your functions, it says to make them "block" if the button is clicked when its display is "none". To fix this, just change "block" to "inline". (**Note:** I kept the "ui" "block" because you just wanted to have the iframes side by side.) Also, to fix a bug that I encountered, make the if statement based on the display being "inline" instead of "none". For example, write `if (x.style.display === 'inline') {x.style.display = 'none';} else {x.style.display = 'inline'};` instead of `if (x.style.display === 'none') {x.style.display = 'inline';} else {x.style.display = 'none';}`. Also, to fix a bug with the no display on loading, just add `document.getElementById("iframeContainer").style.display = "block";` to each function OUTSIDE the if else statement.

Look at the snippet to clearly see what I mean. (It works!)

```js
var frameContainer = document.getElementById("iframeContainer");
function myFunctionui() {

      var x = document.getElementById('ui');

      if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function myFunctiontic() {
      var x = document.getElementById('tic');
      if (x.style.display === 'inline') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      frameContainer.style.display = "block";
    }

    function myFunctionlab() {
      var x = document.getElementById('lab');
      if (x.style.display === 'inline') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      frameContainer.style.display = "block";
    }

    function myFunctionzone1_4() {
      var x = document.getElementById('zone1_4');
      if (x.style.display === 'inline') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      frameContainer.style.display = "block";
    }

    function myFunctionzone5() {
      var x = document.getElementById('zone5');
      if (x.style.display === 'inline') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      frameContainer.style.display = "block";
    }

    function myFunctionslas() {
      var x = document.getElementById('slas');
      if (x.style.display === 'inline') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      frameContainer.style.display = "block";
    }

    function myFunctionhiks() {
      var x = document.getElementById('hiks');
      if (x.style.display === 'inline') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        x.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      frameContainer.style.display = "block";
    }
```

```css
#iframeContainer {white-space: nowrap; display: none;}
#iframeContainer iframe {display: none;}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunctionui()">^</button>

<div id="ui">
  <button onclick="myFunctiontic()">TICs</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionlab()">LABs</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionzone1_4()">ZONE 1-4</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionzone5()">ZONE 5</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionslas()">SLAS</button>
  <button onclick="myFunctionhiks()">HIKS</button>
</div>

<div id="iframeContainer">

  <iframe id="tic"  src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/ticstatus/ticstatus.cgi" width="130" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="lab" src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/labstatus/labstatus.cgi" width="130" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="zone1_4" src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/lastations1_4.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="zone5" src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/lastations5.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="slas" src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/slastations.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="hiks" src="https://itcrops.itap.purdue.edu/opstools/pr/Dev/lastat/hiksstations.cgi" width="250" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! You fixed it!